# Playing mp3 in a Listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

**sorry for my bad english**.. probably you'll see some grammar errors..

I'm learning to program an android application and I need help.
I would like to put some mp3 files in '*res/raw*' folder and i would like to put specific text on each item on the Listview. So when the user clicks on the item he wants (for example a song title), the associated mp3 starts.

I would like if you can teach me how to play just one mp3 at time (beacause the user could clicks many items during the first mp3 playing).
I'm new in the android world so please be patient and use simple terms :)

Have a nice day,
Riccardo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question does not include any specific code of yours I can give you a few guidelines.

1. Declare a class member reference to the MediaPlayer instance. e.g. it should be declared in the class's scope, and not in any method within it:

   ```
   public class MyListView extends ListView {
       private MediaPlayer mp = null;
       //your methods here
   }
   ```
2. In your OnClickListener, check if the instance is null, and if not, stop and release it, and create a new instance with the new song.

   ```
   public void onClick(View v) {
       if (mp != null) {
           mp.stop();
           mp.release();
           mp = MediaPlayer.Create(....);
           mp.start();
       }
   }
   ```
3. If instead of create you decide to use `prepareAsync()`, make sure that you don't call start right after preparation, but instead assign a `OnPreparedListener` and call start in it.

Except of that, follow the guidelines in the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, you helped me about the instance, but.. I don't understand how can I assign an mp3 for each item in the ListView.. Unfortunately, this isn't an event driven language like Visual Basic, and I'm only 16, I have no experience with java and I'm trying to understand it now

Comment: Create an array of the ids of the mp3, and set the appropriate ID according to the index of the view that has been touched.

Comment: BTW, android programming is a lot like event driven programming, using listeners. You can also look here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i

Comment: Uhm.. I did it with buttons, but it haven't a good design if I use buttons... Could I do something like this but using a ListView? just a second, i publish it at pastebin.com

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). You will need to integrate the code in this link in your `listView.setOnItemSelectedListener()` implementation.